# Flow3 - How to initialize and use a global Controller?

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, typo3-flow

I've now some entities, reposetories and controllers in flow3 and they work very well. In case someone needs a global fluid variable (e.g. a username printed in the default layout) he has to define and use a global controller.

How can I create and use such controllers?

Comment: Why do you need a global controller to show a username? Could you give further details? Actually you would have a field users in your model mapped to the users table. From there you have access to all users and their names.

Comment: Yep that is right but you also need to get the User in every single controller. And I don't want to do that for every single controller. So I need a controller which always be called.

Comment: My fault! Didn't see the flow tag. Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Controllers are classes, so you can extend them and create abstract ones.

Let's assume you have `LoveController` in `My.Relationships` package. 
You can create some separate base package i.e. `My.Life` with `AbstractLifeController` inside (php: `abstract class AbstractLifeController extends \TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Controller\ActionController`).

Now there are `initialize*` methods (where * might be Action, View, AnyAction and so on). In your case use: `protected initializeView(\TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\View\ViewInterface $view)` in this abstarct controller and there assign some variables i.e. `$view->assign('myName', $myName);` ...

Then when your `LoveController extends \My\Life\Controller\AbstractLifeController`, that variable `{myName}` will be visible in fluid for templates used by its actions.

So instead of extending \TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Controller\ActionController for all your controllers, just extend this abstract one \My\Life\Controller\AbstractLifeController